# javascript syntax calling object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to call the msgs.loginUsername property, by dynamically grabbing "loginUsername" from the html with jQuery. However, I can't figure out how to structure the syntax to get it to work.

the object:

```
msgs = {
    loginUsername : "Username is required.",
    loginPassword : "Password is required."
};
```

the call:

```
function validateElements(_class) {
var errors = 0;
jQuery(_class).each(function() {
    if (!validate.required(this)) {
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name'); //TROUBLE
        alert(msgs.name);                     //TROUBLE
        errors += 1;
    }
});
return errors > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `msgs[name]` where name = "loginUsername" or "loginPassword"

```
function validateElements(_class) {
var errors = 0;
jQuery(_class).each(function() {
    if (!validate.required(this)) {
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name'); //TROUBLE
        alert(msgs[name]);                     //TROUBLE
        errors += 1;
    }
});
return errors > 0 ? false : true;
}
```